# How to indicate all files in all subdirectories in unix shell?

Tags: wildcard, path, directory

I'm using Max OS X.
I'm trying to copy all header files (*.h) to specific directory (./aaa) from all subdirectories in source directory. (./src/*)
This command worked well.

```
cp ./src/*/*.h ./aaa
```

But I want to copy all header files in the subdirectories in *all* depths. Not only 1st depth.
Is this possible and how to do this? I believe there is an elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find ./src -name '*.h' -exec cp {} ./aaa \;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
find /src -name '*.h' -print0 | xargs -0 cp --target-directory=./aaa
```

(Performs significantly better than -exec for large numbers of files)

Comment: Or you could just use `-exec ... +`.

Comment: Perhaps.  I grew up when that wasn't an option.  I also object to silly quoting rules that seem to be in place for -exec commands.  Finally, xargs is an excellent unix-y tool that everyone should be aware of.  For example, it lets  you do things like ensure that you have three processes running (each having 4 files to handle) at all times while you have the input to work with (taking advantage of mulitple CPUs for e.g. encoding audio files)